# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 in windows 11

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

```
     > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
        > Host name may not contain blanks
  > Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.50.
     > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.3.50/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.3.50.pom'.
        > Host name may not contain blanks
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
[!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying to download...
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

i am trying to setup flutter in windows 11 & i am facing problem while running gradle assemble debug

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem long time ago, doing the following would most likely solve it:

- in case you are using a VPN, make sure that it's giving you a stable internet connection, or turn it off.
- type `flutter clean`

then retry.
note: I have to say that in some rare cases, when I don't have a stable internet connection, some Gradle problems don't get solved unless I delete the `.gradle` file from they system.

Comment: thank you so much !!! i have deleted .gradle file again try to run  the project and work

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you.